# When I go on the police menu in my server the jail menu is called: translation [en][jail menu] does not exist

Tags: lua, fivem

When I go on the police menu in my server the jail menu is called: translation [en][jail menu] does not exist.

I tried to put this in the locales but it did not work.

Here is the code for the scirpt which you have to add to make the jail function working:

```
{label = _U('jail'),value = 'jail'}
```

```
if data2.current.value == 'jail' then
    JailPlayer(GetPlayerServerId(closestPlayer))
end
```

```
function JailPlayer(player)
    ESX.UI.Menu.Open('dialog', GetCurrentResourceName(), 'jail_menu', {
        title = _U('jail_menu_info'),
    }, function (data2, menu)
        local jailTime = tonumber(data2.value)
        if jailTime == nil then
            ESX.ShowNotification('invalid number!')
        else
            TriggerServerEvent("esx_jail:sendToJail", player, jailTime * 60)
            menu.close()
        end
    end, function (data2, menu)
        menu.close()
    end)
end
```

I tried to put this in the locales but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the title which in this case is `_U('jail_menu_info'),` defined with a translation. Alternative you could just type in what you want. Here is how you can do that.

```
    ESX.UI.Menu.Open('dialog', GetCurrentResourceName(), 'jail_menu', {
            title = 'PUT_THE_TITLE_HERE',
        }, function (data2, menu)
```